# Client side Error at IP address in Java file transfer code using Sockets?

Tags: java, socket.io, file-transfer

I have started learning Java socket programming few days back. I found this code on some website for transferring a file from server to multiple clients (multithreading, using thread pools).

When I run this application using loopback interface(127.0.0.1) it works fine and file gets transferred to destination folder. But when I connect the server pc (192.168.1.2) to client pc (192.168.1.3), the exception occurs and says

```
"Could not establish I/O for IP: <ipaddress of client> <port number>"
```

The client and server pc are connected well with Ethernet cable and ping each other. No firewall between them. Am very new to the site and beginner in java sockets.

Can please anyone help me to debug or understand the error?

```
Client Side Code: 2 Java files
myfileclient.java // First File

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myfileclient {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String fileName = file.getName();
    //System.out.println("You have selected: " + filename);


    String serverAddress= "127.0.0.1";
    int serverPort=  4444;
    //String fileName = "D:\\a.pdf";


    //Create Socket
    System.out.println("client >Creating Socket to " + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Client: Connecting to: " + serverAddress + serverPort + "\nClient Connecting....." + "\nClient Requesting file : " + fileName ,"Success",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    SocketHandling client = new SocketHandling(serverAddress, serverPort);

    //Connect
    System.out.println("client >Connecting");
    client.connect();

    //File request
    System.out.println("client >Requesting file : " + fileName);

    client.requestFile("D:\\a.pdf");

    //Close all
    System.out.println("client >Close Connection");
    client.close();
}

}

SocketHandling.java // Second File

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SocketHandling {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter socketWriter;
    private BufferedReader socketReader;
    public String destIpAddress;
    public int destPort;

    public SocketHandling(String destIpAddress, int destPort) {



        this.destIpAddress = destIpAddress;
        this.destPort = destPort;
    }

    public void connect() {

        try {
            //Create socket
            client = new Socket(this.destIpAddress,this.destPort);


            //Create read/write buffers for socket
            socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            socketWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Unkown host: " + destIpAddress);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not establish I/O for IP: "+ destIpAddress + " on port: " + destPort);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Could not establish I/O for IP: "+ destIpAddress + " on port: " + destPort,"Error",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void requestFile(String filename) throws IOException {

        //Timers
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;

        //Hard coded temporary file size 
        int filesize=7000000; 

        //Send File Name to server
        socketWriter.println(filename);
        socketWriter.flush();

        //Get n and m
        String message = (String)socketReader.readLine();

        //Split string up
        String[] tokens = message.split("[,]");
        int ConnectionCounter = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        int FileCounter = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);


        if(FileCounter >= 0){
            //File exists
            System.out.println("client >File " + filename + " was found at the serve"); 
            System.out.println("client >Server handled " + ConnectionCounter + " requests, " + FileCounter + " request were successsful.");
            //Receive file
            System.out.println("client >Downloading file " + filename);


            byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
            InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\copy.pdf"); //Files Added to Download directory 
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
            current = bytesRead;

            do {
                bytesRead =
                        is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("client >Download complete (" + (end-start) + "ms)");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File:" + filename + " was found at the Server\nServer handled " + ConnectionCounter + "requests" + FileCounter + " requests were successsful!!\nDownloading file.....\nDownload complete!! (" + (end-start) + "ms) ","Success",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            bos.close();

        }else{
            //Files does not exists
            //System.out.println("client >File " + filename + " was not found at the serve");       
            System.out.println("client >Connection Counter : " + ConnectionCounter + "   File Counter : " + FileCounter);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File " + filename + " was not found at the Server ","Error",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            //Closes read/write buffers and the socket
            socketWriter.close();
            socketReader.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Server Side Code: 4 Java files

```
    myfileserver.java // First File

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class myfileserver {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Server: Start");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server Started ","Success",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        Multithreading server = new Multithreading(4444);
        server.run();

    }
}

Multithreading.java // Second File

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.BindException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Multithreading implements Runnable{

private ServerSocket server;
private ExecutorService pool;

public Multithreading(int listenPort) {

    this.pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50); //Max connections

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(listenPort);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public void run() {
     try {

         while(true) {
            pool.execute(new WorkerThread(server.accept()));
         }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


}

ServerStatistics.java // Third File

public class ServerStatistics {


private static int ConnectionCounter;   //M
private static int FileCounter;         //N

public static synchronized  int getConnectionCounter(){
    return ConnectionCounter;
}

public static synchronized  int getFileCounter(){
    return FileCounter; 
}

public static synchronized  int IncConnectionCounter(){
    return ConnectionCounter++;
}

public static synchronized  int IncFileCounter(){
    return FileCounter++;   
}
}


WorkerThread.java // Fourth File

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    public Socket connection;

    public  WorkerThread(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        handleConnection();
    }

    private synchronized boolean  handleConnection() {
        try {
            //Increment Connection statistics 
            ServerStatistics.IncConnectionCounter();

            //Create read/write buffers for the socket
            PrintWriter streamWriter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader  streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            //Get filename from client 
            String fileName =  streamReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("server> File " + fileName + " requested from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());



            try{
                File myFile = new File (fileName); //Files Are in the Upload directory 

                if(myFile.exists()){
                    //File exists
                    ServerStatistics.IncFileCounter();

                    System.out.println("server> Successful, " + fileName + " exists");
                    System.out.println("server> Total successful requests so far = " + ServerStatistics.getFileCounter() + " out of " + ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter());

                    //Send N and M
                    streamWriter.println(ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter() + "," + ServerStatistics.getFileCounter());
                    streamWriter.flush();

                    //Create File buffer to read file to socket
                    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();

                    //Send File
                    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                    os.flush();
                    connection.close();

                    System.out.println("server> File transfer complete [" + fileName + "]");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File " + fileName + " requested from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() +"\nSuccessful File exists!!" +"\nTotal successful requests so far = " + ServerStatistics.getFileCounter() + " out of " + ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter() + "\nFile transfer complete [" + fileName + "]" ,"",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                }else{
                    //File does not exists
                    System.out.println("server> Not Successful, " + fileName + " does not exists");
                    System.out.println("server> Total successful requests so far = " + ServerStatistics.getFileCounter() + " out of " + ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter());

                    //Send N and -1 b/c file does not exists
                    streamWriter.println(ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter() + "," + (-1)); 
                    streamWriter.flush();
                }

                return true;
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                streamWriter.println(ServerStatistics.getConnectionCounter() + ",-1");
                streamWriter.flush();
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soomeone please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

a) the obvious change of:

```
String serverAddress= "127.0.0.1";
    int serverPort=  4444;
```

to

```
String serverAddress= "192.168.1.2";
    int serverPort=  4444;
```

b) I would start to check 192.168.1.2, you can do a netstat -an when your Server is running and verify it is listening into the right port, also  I would get a packet capture in Server to see if TCP request comes from Client.

Comment: Thanks @spicyramen. I will try this again since I did earlier but has same error. Let you know back if it works this time.